# AC adapter won't power fan at full speed

Tags: ac-dc, wall-wart

I have a spare 92mm case fan rated 12V and ~600mA I've used to build a solder fume extractor. When I was prototyping it, I tested the fan with a 12V 2.5A AC adapter and it worked fine, ran at full speed, and was drawing 450-460 mA. I didn't want to tie up that AC adapter with this device, so I purchased a 12V 1A AC adapter to dedicate to the project.

I finished the project today and plugged in the new 12V 1A adapter. The fan would not run at full speed, and the speed surged up and down about once per second. I checked the adapter and it is putting out 12V, and I do have the polarity correct, and the fan is rotating the correct direction.

I tested it again with the larger adapter, and it is still drawing around 450mA, and the fan runs at full speed with that adapter.

I can't imagine what might be going wrong here. Do I have a bad adapter, or am I missing something?

Edit: I've figured it out. Turns out I had another 12V 1A adapter in an old Radio Shack kit, and it gave me the same poor result. I tried again with the 2.5A adapter, and this time checked the *startup* current: approximately 1.5A. The 1A adapters just can't supply enough current to get the motor to start up to full speed. I just need a higher capacity adapter.

Comment: you have an adapter that cannot run that fan .... the adapter may or may not be bad

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, can you trace the voltage across your fan/supply terminals?

Comment: just an LED (and resistor) would probably show the problem.